# Как задать кнопке PyQt5 преимущественный(приоритетный) размер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qpushbutton

У меня есть код, который я оставлю ниже.

Класс `Label` принимает путь к изображению и   закругляет его края. Из-за некоторых обстоятельств буду использовать его экземпляры вместо кнопок.

В классе `MyWindow` я создаю два QGridLayout'а(`box1` и `box2`).

- В первый контейнер(`box1`) добавляю кнопку `button` и второй контейнер(`box2`).
- Второй контейнер наполняю двумя виджетами QLabel, которые получаю из `Label`.

Первый виджет QLabel `label1` использую вместо кнопки - привязываю к нему метод `click`, которой очищает второй контейнер(`box2`) и создает внутри него новую кнопку.

К сожалению, после удаления виджетов из `box2` и заполнения этого контейнера чем-нибудь новым(в моем случае, кнопкой), **размер контейнера меняется, и кнопка `button` начинает терроризировать мое окно, разрастаясь до непозволительно больших размеров**:(

---

**До нажатия на QLabel:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**После нажатия QLabel:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для меня предугадать расположение и размеры виджетов при изменении чего-либо очень сложно, но использовать абсолютное позиционирование с помощью метода `setGeometry()` я не хочу. **Хочу задать приоритетный размер кнопки `button`, чтобы нажатие на QLabel приводило примерно к следующему:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На моей схеме **размеры виджета `button` одинаковы в обоих ситуациях**. Вообще, как я уже говорил выше, плохо понимаю все то, что касается размеров и положения виджета на экране, поэтому мог сказать какую-нибудь глупость. **Вот мой код:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)
        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.label1 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.label2 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)

    def click(self):
        for row in range(self.box2.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.box2.columnCount()):
                w = self.box2.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
                w.deleteLater()

        self.box2.addWidget(self.new_button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать то, что описывал выше?
Я планировал ненадолго отойти, поэтому могу не сразу ответить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
self.button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
```

> void QWidget::setFixedSize(int w, int h)
>
> Устанавливает ширину виджета на w и высоту на h.

если это не подходит, напишите.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.button.setFixedSize(60, 60)                             # <----

        self.box1.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)

        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.label1 = Label('im.png')
        self.label2 = Label('Ok.png')
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)

    def click(self):
        for row in range(self.box2.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.box2.columnCount()):
                w = self.box2.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
                w.deleteLater()

        self.box2.addWidget(self.new_button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Как задать кнопке PyQt5 преимущественный размер?')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здорово, это то, что я хотел, спасибо вам большое!